# Serialize AST in parsable format 

Tags: compiler-construction, backend, abstract-syntax-tree

I have a DSL with Java front-end and I would like to serialize an AST that I get in front-end part in some easily parsable format to make it easier to write a back-end part that generates a code in different programming languages. Is there is anything better than XML for this purpose?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

XML produces lots of text, and ASTs can be phenomenally big.   (I build parsers and) our parsers will produce XML because our customers demanded it... but none of them actually use it.   IMHO, it is better to design a custom format that encodes your tree densely, to avoid the time it takes to read and write the ASTs.  For instance, you might settle for:

```
( nodetype =value childnodes )
```

where ( ) are parentheses,  with ( opening the tree node, the nodetype is an integer representing the node type [maybe even in a high-radix format to minimize character count], = is present if the node carries a value [you don't really need the = sign if you think about it], and the value is provided.  The childnodes are inlined before the closing ); if they are present, they obviously start with a left paren.   No spaces needed!  If you actually need to *read* this sometimes, you can build a simple dumb tool to indent the parentheses when you need to see it.

[Old timers will recognize this as LISP S-expressions, and this has been around since the late 1950s as a tree encoding].

(We avoid this altogether pretty much because reading and writing trees is expensive no matter how you do it, and its often just easier and more efficient to finish processing the tree you have in memory and just spit out the final answer).

Comment: I almost always use S-expressions similar to those described above. That way, the back-end generation can be done using function bindings and evaluation. (e.g. 1+2 becomes (+ 1 2) and "+" evaluates to a funtion that knows what to produce for itself, the "1" and the "2.")  You can also use postfix expressions, which are quicker to serialize, but they are harder to read and harder to back-end to something other than a stack machine.